# How can I use lodash with ejs?

Tags: javascript, ejs, lodash

I work with `ejs`, and I try to do something like:

```
<%= _.find(db.sections,{type: 'Features'}) %>
```

And the site crashed.

when I wrote in `app.js` this line:

```
var features = _.find(dbObject.sections, {type: "Features"});
```

It's work fine.

in app.js there is: `var _ = require('lodash');`
and I call home.ejs with:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('home', {db: dbObject} )
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but in general you do not want to do any kind of processing of data in your view template. Transform your data object into the view model in the controller or elsewhere, then let the template just render, like nature intended.

Comment: I dont "processing" it, I just look for some part of this.

Comment: @user3202422 sure you are, you are trying to filter it in the view. Can easily do that in controller

Comment: @charlietfl, but then I'll need to pass all the filters via the params, and that will be very very long list of params. still I have to prefer this?

Comment: I haven't worked with ejs much ... might try `require` in template file and see what happens. There are likely some docs on how to do this

Comment: require also give error :(

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution :

In Your app.js

```
const _ = require("lodash");
app.locals._ = _;
```

Where `app` is a `express()` app. So in the ejs template, just use it normally :

```
<a href="posts/<%= _.lowerCase(post.title) %>">Read More</a>
```

Credits go to [Aran Cloverink on medium](https://cloverinks.medium.com/)